# How to Read .Doc Template File and Edit Template with Values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I have a document template and I want to use that template for merging client information with that (Replacing <>, <> <> with our information from database.

To do this i first need to read the document, update the fields and then save it with tag replaced data.

Can any one please help me to visualize this; how to do this and using what tools?

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: if you have MS Word installed on all machines where you want to run the program you can use Word Automation, which can be used by C#

Comment: Server side Office/Word automation is a dead end per KB257757. Don't try to trouble yourself.

Comment: MS may officially state that Office Automation is not recommended or supported server-side, but it works as long as you're careful to handle unexpected responses and hangs.  You just need to log in as the service users and enxure that Office is setup so that when it opens it doesn't show any dialog prompts (as the automation cannot handle them).  I currently use and support an application using server-side Office Automation - yes it was painstaking to setup, but once configured its stable.

Comment: I'm Assuming your not using word 2007+ due to the `.doc` extension?

Comment: In addition to putting <> in the text of the document, there are at least two other approaches: traditional mail merge, which uses field codes, and content control data binding. Both of these are better, since they get around the issue of <customer> being split across runs (and failing to match).  Do you care which you use? (This may come down to who is authoring the templates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer from http://docx.codeplex.com/ tool. It is really super cool tool to do modification in your document template.

Consider this - with minimal efforts to make it ready for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use OpenXML technology to manipulate the word document and insert dynamic content into the word document. 
I assume that you are using docx word documents for this purpose. The docx file is actually a zipped file which has many xml files, which inturn can be manipulated using the OpenXML API using c#. In your case, the contents of the word will be in an xml called "document.xml". You will have to read this XML and replace the <> placeholder with your data from database.
I have written 2 articles (with source code) with respect to these concepts. You can use the following links which can give a heads-up.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Word_2007_Footnote.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Word_2007_Images.aspx

Though it might not give you the exact solution to the specific problem you have, you can use this to start off with something (like how to read the document.xml using OpenXML API and c#), and then you can work on your own to fix your problem.

EDIT: Did not notice you mentioned .doc file. I saw the OpenXML tag to it, hence replied. I guess this solution applies only if the document is .docx.

Comment: Hey Abey This would work out. Using Open XML how can we modify data? Please let me know

Comment: As I said, it would work out if your document template is a docx file. In the docx file, do have your <XXXXData1>, <XXXXData2> placeholders. At runtime, you could change the placeholder value to something from a datasource using OpenXML APIs.  Please do go through the source code available in the first link. It is very straight-forward. I can help you if you have doubts. Thanks!

Comment: Well i have few placeholders in my header, few in footer and rest in body part. Can you please guide from where i can get the code or working model for this? I have templates in these sections.. please let me know how can i do that?

Comment: Click the link "Download Source Code" in the link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Word_2007_Footnote.aspx. The source code contains Footnotes.sln solution. The source code in it can help you start off.

Comment: Alternately you can get help from http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com/. WordDocumentGenerator is an utility/samples to generate Word documents from templates using Visual Studio 2010 and Open XML 2.0 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You may talk to an Aspose presale to see if the components help,

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Besides, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 has Word automation services,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742315.aspx

Don't try to use service side Office automation, as it is a dead end,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for 'mail merge' feature for Word documents. Please see the help topics in the '[Mail Merge and Reporting](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/mail-merge-and-reporting.html)' section of Aspose.Words for .NET documentation.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com/) is multi-platform tool that can use .doc file as templates and populate via a mail-merge like process.  By default it uses document fields and in plain text the <<field>> notation.