# Edit Word template in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I'm stuck in a project for school.

I have a word template, this is a empty document but it has some formatting, for example, each page has 25 lines, the font is Times New Roman and its size 12.

What I have to do is to open this template, write information and save it. When I open the template I should see the text displayed respecting the format.

How can I do this? I tried DocX library but I couldn't make work Line Spacing feature.

You can user whatever you want to make it work. It must be in C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877328/how-to-read-doc-template-file-and-edit-template-with-values - maybe this might help?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36694/Creation-of-a-Word-2007-document-using-the-Open-XM

Comment: can you use Interop classes?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be C#? Maybe they want you to use [vba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)?